# Add a new binding to allBindingsAccessor

Tags: knockout.js

**Update:** The really problem was solved by using "valueAllowUnset" (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements) I'd still like to know if adding to allBindingsAccessor is possible and how to do it.

I have been trying to create bindingHandler that prevents an observable from getting set to undefined by a `<select>` before the options are loaded. (In my case the options are loaded via ajax)

The issue I'm running into is I want to add 'value' to allBindingsAccessor once options are populated and when I do I get an exception: 'undefined is not a function'.

I can see that the newBinding is missing Get() and Has() that is causing the error.  What I can't figure out is what should I do differently.

Here's the bindingHandler: **(FYI: This is not the correct way to do what I needed, but I'd still like to understand if doing something like this is possible.)**

```
(function() {
  var originalInit = ko.bindingHandlers.options.init;
  var originalUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.options.update;
  ko.bindingHandlers.myOptions = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
      var optionsArr = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      if (optionsArr === undefined || optionsArr.length === 0) return;

      var myVal = allBindingsAccessor.get("myValue");
      if (myVal === undefined || myVal === null) return;

      var newBindings = function() {
        var tmpBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        tmpBindings.value = myVal;
        return tmpBindings;
      };

      originalUpdate(element, valueAccessor, newBindings, viewModel);
    }
  };
})();
```

And a plunk that shows this: http://plnkr.co/edit/8fgrIE2NtzLJ8UkSoicu

Comment: Have you looked at the `valueAllowUnset` option?  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements It was designed to help handle cases where the options come in later.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!  So that actually get's me past my issue, but my question still remains.  Can you add to allBindingsAccessor?